# Theme Changer- Help

Tags: javascript, html

i have buttons on a page and when the user clicks onto that button, the color of the page changes. basically i`m creating a theme changer. my code is this :

function Red()
{
    var Redbtn = document.getElementById("btnRed");
    Redbtn.bgColor = "#F00";
}

function Blue()
{
}

Theme changer

i`have done upto the red button but the color of the page do not appears to be red.. please help where i`m getting problem.

Answer (score 0):

in your html,

```
<button class="button" id="redButton" /> Red </button>
<button class="button" id="blueButton" /> Blue </button>
<button class="button" id="greenButton" /> Green </button>
```

in your js file,

$(document).ready(function(){

```
$('#redButton').click(function() {
    $('body').css('background-color', '#FF0000');
});

$('#greenButton').click(function() {
    $('body').css('background-color', '#00FF00');
});

$('#blueButton').click(function() {
    $('body').css('background-color', '#0000FF');
});
```

});